# Error - RSpec - expect method is escaping '\n'

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I would like to assert this expectation:

```
contas_csv = transacoes_decorator.converter_contas_para_csv
expect(contas_csv).to eq('345,30000\n350,19500\n355,20000\n360,-31000\n')
```

I got this error:

```
 expected: "345,30000\\n350,19500\\n355,20000\\n360,-31000\\n"
      got: "345,30000\n350,19500\n355,20000\n360,-31000\n"
```

I printed the **contas_csv** variable, and I got what I expected "345,30000\n350,19500\n355,20000\n360,-31000\n"

But the RSpec is adding an extra '\' before the '\n'. Because of it, my test is failing.

Someone can help me with that, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using single quotes so special characters like `\n` are taken literally, not expanded to their control-character counterparts.

Use this:

```
"...\n..."
```

With double quotes. `'\n'` is the same as `"\\n"`.